# Solving 2 equations with 2 unknowns

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I have a question regarding two equations.

Imagine an object traveling at 1 m/s and 90 degrees relative to the surface, such that the x-component is in the direction perpendicular to the surface. In the 90 degree case, the y component is 0. Thus the x-component is 1 m/s. If I wanted to have the angle between the object and surface be 89 degrees, the velocity needs to have a y-component. How do I calculate the y-component associated with a degree change of 1 degree?

First I know that:

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 1 \text{ m/s}$$

and I think:

$$\tan(\theta) = x/y$$

Maybe its degrees or radians I am dealing with, but I would appreciate some guidance in this problem

Comment: I think you'll find tan is x/y

Comment: good point, just edited it.

Comment: $cos(\theta)={y\over 1}\\sin(\theta)={x\over1}$

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange that you would say "I wanted to have the angle between the object and surface be 89 degrees" and **then** say "Maybe its degrees or radians I am dealing with"!   Since you are given the angle in **degrees**, of course you are dealing with degrees.

Yes, since the distance from the origin to (x, y) is 1, $\sqrt{x^2+ y^2}= 1$  Squaring both sides, $x^2+ y^2= 1$.  Yes, $\frac{x}{y}= tan(89)= 57.3$ so that x= 57.3y and then $x^2+ y^2= (57.3y)^2+ y^2= 3284.29y^2= 1$.  So $y= \sqrt{\frac{1}{3284.29}}= 0.01745$